# nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `com.xyz.pqr.model.Date`

Tags: java, xml, rest, jackson, jaxb

Error:

I generated Java POJOs from XSD using JAXB. Now I am trying to consume a XML payload. But I am running into the following:

> "Bad Request","message":"JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of `com.xyz.pqr.model.Date` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('01/01/2012'); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `com.xyz.pqr.model.Date` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('01/01/2012')\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 3419] (through reference chain: com.xyz.pqr.model.DATA[\"residentAddress\"]->com.xyz.pqr.model.Address[\"fromDate\"])","path":"/receiveXML"} .

Controller :

```
    @PostMapping(path="/receiveXML", consumes="application/xml")
    public String receiveXml(@RequestBody DATA xml) {

        return "XML Received";
    }
```

Curl :

```
curl -X POST --header "Content-Type:application/xml;charset=UTF-8" --data @soap_get.xml http://localhost:8080/receiveXML
```

Can anyone point me to the right direction? Do I need to have some kind of binding file to parse the string to Date?

Jackson Dependencies:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-module-parameter-names</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-datatype-jdk8</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Address Field inside DATA
@XMLRootElement
public class DATA

protected Address residentAddress; -- This one has no annotations

Date inside Address  class :
 @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected Date fromDate;

XSD:

```
<xs:complexType name="address">
 \\
 \\
   <xs:element name="fromDate" type="date"/>
\\
\\
<xs:complexType name="address">


<xs:complexType name="date">
<xs:simpleContent>
<xs:extension base="dateBase">
<xs:attribute name="formatString">
<xs:simpleType>
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
<xs:enumeration value="shortDate">
<xs:annotation>
<xs:documentation>equivalent of MM/dd/yyyy</xs:documentation>
</xs:annotation>
</xs:enumeration>
<xs:enumeration value="MM/dd/yyyy"/>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
</xs:attribute>
</xs:extension>
</xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

Comment: Can you show the sources of  your `DATA` and `Address` classes, because the error says the problem occured there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue by getting rid of all the jackson dependencies I put above.